# Change Resize Icon Position

Tags: html, css, angular

i want to change the position from resize icon on the bottom right to right side in the middle.

[image]

is it possible to do that?

Comment: Are you trying to change the resize icon of textarea?

Comment: no,  i want to change the position from the icon. for example i want to move the icon on the right side but in the middle. something like that.